# how to Cartesian multiply which describe the ratios of two dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx

I have two dictionaries, like these:

```
first_dict = {"key1": 1, "key2":2, "key3":3}
sec_dict = {"key1": 2, "key2": 3, "key3":4}
```

and I want to use networkx or numpy to have a matrix as below:

```
[[1/2, 2/2, 3/2],
 [1/3, 2/3, 3/3], 
 [3/2, 3/3, 3/4]]
```

which discribe the ratio of every node in first_dict and sec_dict.
can someone help me about this?

Comment: Why do you want to use numpy or networkx? None of them is related to your problem. Perhaps you want to use pandas?

Comment: you can easily do this just using the python standard library

Comment: I want to have a network with these dictionaries and my dictionaries are bigger than my examples @DYZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following NumPy solution work. You have to sort the dictionaries before you extract the values unless you are sure that they are already in sorted order.

```
_, vals1 = zip(*sorted(first_dict.items()))
_, vals2 = zip(*sorted(sec_dict.items()))
```

If they have been previously sorted, you can ignore sorting:

```
vals1 = list(first_dict.values())
vals2 = list(sec_dict.values())

np.array(vals1).reshape(-1,1) / np.array(vals2)

#array([[0.5       , 0.33333333, 0.25      ],
#       [1.        , 0.66666667, 0.5       ],
#       [1.5       , 1.        , 0.75      ]])
```

Comment: I know but my dictionaries have about 200k keys, and I guess some package solves this problem, with better performance and implementations.